# dhtmlx календарь в input

Tags: javascript, html

Вот этот код записывает Данные календдаря на DIV

```
    var myCalendar;
    var logObj;
    var logInd = 0;
    var logData = [];

    function doOnLoad() {

        myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject("calendarHere");
        myCalendar.hideTime();
        myCalendar.show();

        myCalendar.attachEvent("onChange", function(d){
            logData.push((++logInd)+") "+myCalendar.getFormatedDate("%F %Y",d));
            writeLog();
        });
        myCalendar.attachEvent("onArrowClick", function(d_old,d_new){
            logData.push((++logInd)+") onArrowClick event, "+myCalendar.getFormatedDate("%F %Y",d_new));
            writeLog();
        });
    }


    function writeLog() {
        if (!logObj) logObj = document.getElementById("logsHere2");
        var t = "";
        for (var q=logData.length-1; q>=Math.max(logData.length-6,0); q--) t += logData[q]+"<br>";
        logObj.innerHTML = t;
    }

    <div id="logsHere2"></div>
```

Пытаюсь записать в инпут таким образом не получаеться в чем может быть проблема ?

```
    <input type="text" name="name" id="logsHere2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы записать что-то в `input` нужно вместо `var input.innerHTML` написать `var input.value`

```js
   var myCalendar;
    var logObj;
    var logInd = 0;
    var logData = [];

    function doOnLoad() {

        myCalendar = new dhtmlXCalendarObject("calendarHere");
        myCalendar.hideTime();
        myCalendar.show();

        myCalendar.attachEvent("onChange", function(d){
            logData.push((++logInd)+") "+myCalendar.getFormatedDate("%F %Y",d));
            writeLog();
        });
        myCalendar.attachEvent("onArrowClick", function(d_old,d_new){
            logData.push((++logInd)+") onArrowClick event, "+myCalendar.getFormatedDate("%F %Y",d_new));
            writeLog();
        });
    }


    function writeLog() {
        if (!logObj) logObj = document.getElementById("logsHere2");
        var t = "";
        for (var q=logData.length-1; q>=Math.max(logData.length-6,0); q--) t += logData[q]+"<br>";
        logObj.value = t;
    }
```

```css
input {width: 200px; background: violet; border: 2px solid purple; color: black;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="logsHere2" />
```

Можете так попробовать, чтоб в `input` записывалось только одно значение:

```js
    function writeLog() {
        if (!logObj) logObj = document.getElementById("logsHere2");
        var t = "";
        for (var q=logData.length-1; q>=Math.max(logData.length-6,0); 
         q--) t = logData[q];
        logObj.value = t;
      }
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, Eugen Eray, Всё работает. Код не мой как Вы уже поняли это dhtmlx календарь. Возник ещё один вопрос : при нажатии на дату в поле для инпута значения записываются через запятую а как сделать чтоб там было только одно значение а при выборе другой даты значение в инпуте поменялось т е туда не добавлял другие даты а было чтоб только одно ?

Comment: @AlexStassov Сейчас попробую дополнить ответ.

Comment: Был бы очень признателен Вам !

Comment: @AlexStassov Дополнил ответ.

Comment: К сожалению не получилось ( убрал даже тег <br> хотя думаю что он роли не играл никакой (

Comment: @AlexStassov  Кстати – есть же описание плагина: https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCalendar/samples/01_init/01_attach_to_input.html

Comment: Есть описание но это прикрепленный календарь к инпуту. Т е когда выбераете там дату он исчезает т е он постонно не отображается. А то что я код дал это прикрепленный к блоку (DIV) он постоянно виден на странице мне надо из этого взять значение

Comment: то что я Вам показал это отсюда https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCalendar/samples/05_events/06_onchange_onarrowclick.html он там заполняет div

Comment: Eugen Eray, если Вам не трудно подскажите как сделать чтоб можно было выбрать только одну дату. А то совсем замучался уже 3 день ищу. Но вы 80 процентов моего вопроса уже решили за что большое человеческое спасибо Вам !

Comment: @AlexStassov Еще один вариант предоставил, может поможет. А на счет даты, я не знаю – не пользовался этим плагином.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое ) Вы мне очень помогли дай Бог Вам здоровья )) Всё получилось. А насчет даты я сделал ГГГГ-ММ-ДД (ну в формат mysql) а то что он сперва ставит число перед скобкой отрезал на php через substr_replace )))

Comment: @AlexStassov  Рад, что помогло.